# What is the difference between 'us' and 'ourselves' in the following sentences?

Tags: personal-pronouns, reflexive-pronouns

What's the difference in meaning between the following two sentences?

- Sometimes we look to others to convince us of what we want to believe.
- Sometimes we look to others to convince ourselves of what we want to believe.

I think that "to convince us" in the first means "for others to convince us" and that "to convince ourselves" in the second means "for us to convince ourselves".

Comment: It would help people to answer if you edit to explain what you think the difference might be and what research you have already done.

Comment: In your context, the reflexive pronoun *(**ourselves**)* is just a slightly more emphatic alternative to the "flat" pronoun *(**us**)*. For even greater emphasis, it could be rephrased as *Sometimes we look to others to convince **us** of what we **ourselves** want to believe.* But for this *specific* example, it seems to me the same relevant emphasis might be better conveyed by *...to convince us of what we **already** [want to] believe.*

Comment: Convince yourself is not having someone else convince you.

Answer (score 1):

The first sentence has an extra possible meaning which the second does not have.

Both sentences can mean, "*Sometimes we **try to convince ourselves** of what we already want to believe by looking at other people*."

The first sentence can also mean, "*Sometimes we **get other people to convince us** of what we already want to believe.*"

To "look to someone to [verb]" can mean "expect someone else to [verb]".

When I first read your first sentence, I thought it meant "get other people to convince us" until I read the second.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with FumbleFingers that the reflexive is being used here as an intensifier. That is a frequent use of reflexive pronouns.

> He told me so himself

merely emphasizes that whoever he is is indeed the one who told me.

I see no reason to doubt that “ourselves” here is used an intensifier. As a matter of style, however, I agree with you that it is hard to construe. We did not convince ourselves. That is, a better way to express what was intended is

> Sometimes we look to others to convince us of what we already want to believe.

The use of the reflexive just muddies the waters. I am not saying that the use of “ourselves” is ungrammatical or unidiomatic. I am merely saying that I doubt that it expresses the intended thought as clearly as possible.